# Django and pgAdmin not aligned

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I was trying to change the order of the table columns in a postgreSQL table. As I am just starting, it seemed easier to `manage.py flush` and create a new DB with new name and apply migrations.

I can see the new DB in pgAdmin received all the Django models migrations except my app model/table. I deleted all migrations folder (except `0001_initial.py`) and still, when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` I get:

```
No changes detected
```

But the model class table is not in the DB. When I try to migrate the app model it says:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Is there any way to delete all tables, `makemigrations` and `migrate` and postgres get all the tables? Any idea why postgreSQL/pgAdmin cannot get my Django app model/table?

Comment: Why is pgAdmin tagged here?

Comment: @AdityaToshniwal I removed it although the misalignment is between the 2 (Django-PGAdmin)

Comment: Thanks. pgAdmin is UI tool to manage PostgreSQL. The issue was with PostgreSQL migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a particular app migration using below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The app specific migrations in my case were not working.

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

What did the trick is to modify the models adding an additional fake variable, then all the variables (and not only the additional one) gets picked up by the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command. It is not a clever solution but it did the trick.